# How to do automatic failover for legacy vb apps

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, vb6

We are using old Visual Basic apps to connect to our database server to do some internal processing. We have implemented database mirroring on AWS. So, if a database fails, it automatically fails over to database mirror. But since the connection strings in visual basic apps are hard coded, they are failing to connect.

What are our options to do automatic failover to mirror server from legacy apps? Please note that we are using AWS to host all our servers.

Comment: You don't have the source code for the VB6 apps?

Comment: I have the source code. so, I can change it but I am not sure what to change so that it works automatically.

Comment: Change the connection string, for example https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/database-mirroring/

Comment: Does this work in Old Visual Basic applications?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a Text file and put your connection string in there. Don't forget to encrypt the file. Place the text file in some shared folder so that all your VB clients can access it.
2. Have your VB Program Read the connection string from the text file.
3. Change your connection string either manually or use any of the software to detect the failover and change it automatically

Hope this helps